# Update cell when DELETE pressed

Tags: excel, vba

I have below data:

```
Mon    Tue    Total
2      5       25
5      0       50
54     85      5485
```

At the moment I concatenate Total using Mon & Tue. This works fine using on change event when double clicking in the cell or pasting values in Mon and Tue.

However, is there a way of reflecting the changes when DELETE button is pressed? So when DELETE, clear Total cells. So if I delete Mon, just have 5 and if I delete Mon and Tue, empty cell for the first row etc...

**UPD:**
My current code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets(1).Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=A2:A" & lngLastRow & "&""""&" & "B2:B" & lngLastRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: show please your current code. Btw, why not just use formula `=A2 & B2`?

Comment: Have you tried putting your code inside a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` function?

Comment: Hi have the code already inside the Worksheet_Change. But it does not work when you highlight a range and press Delete.

Comment: @simoco My code so far is: `code` Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lngLastRow As Long

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets(1).Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow).Value = Evaluate("=A2:A" & lngLastRow & "&""""&" & "B2:B" & lngLastRow)

End Sub `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A", "B:B")) Is Nothing Then 
Range("D2:D" & myRange).Value = myValue 

End If
```